# Slanted box shadow on left and right side

Tags: css, box-shadow

I am trying to make slanted box shadow on both sides of a div, which I have added here as an image.[image]
The red part is indicating here shadow. actually color is *not solid*, it should  gradually decrease when it is moving to outside from border.

Comment: Based on exactly what you want I think using a js canvas is your best bet, you can get the attributes of box and draw the back(red) in yourself zindex = -1

Comment: but I need to done this through CSS only!!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background: white;
}
div:before{
  content:' ';
  display:block;
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, black);
  position: fixed;
  transform:   matrix3d(1.1,0,0.00,0,0.00,0.71,0.71,0.0007,0,-0.71,0.71,0,0,37,0,1);  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my contribution hope it gives you a baseline.

```css
  .box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
  }
  .box-content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }

  .box::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 180px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid red;
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  .box::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 180px solid transparent;
    border-left: 25px solid red;
    position: absolute; 
    right: -4px;
    bottom: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box">
   <div class="box-content">
      Box
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. But actually I need shadow that is not of solid color. I mean color should be gradually decrease when moving to outside from side border.

Comment: Okay you can specify an opacity or use an rgba color in that case or use a gradient color instead

Answer (score 2):

Using [**`transform: skew()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) applied to the div's `before` and `after`

[**jsFiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/vfu93de7/1/)

**code:**

```css
#test {
  width: 150px;
  height: 220px;
  line-height: 220px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px black solid;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 150px;
}
#test:before, #test:after {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -11px;
  z-index: -1;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  transform: skew(5deg, 0);
}
#test:after {
  transform: skew(-5deg, 0);
  left: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Box</div>
```

---

**EDIT :** to give the shadow effect some real blur with gradient and transparency, we could make use of [**`linear-gradient`**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp) background with two `rgba()` values, as well as CSS [**`blur()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter#blur()_2) <sup>**(1)**</sup> filter.

[**jsFiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/vfu93de7/2/)

**code:**

```css
#test {
  width: 150px;
  height: 220px;
  line-height: 220px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px black solid;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 150px;
}
#test:before, #test:after {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -11px;
  z-index: -1;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  transform: skew(5deg, 0);
  filter: blur(2px);
}
#test:after {
  transform: skew(-5deg, 0);
  left: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Box</div>
```

---

**Notes:**

<sup>**(1)**</sup> [browser support for CSS filter](http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20filter)

Comment: I realy like the blur, even if it is not part of the question. Unfortunately a real shadow-blur is more blur on the top and more sharp on the bottom. Could you add a second sharp-shadow over the blur-shadow and move the blur-shadow 3 pixel up? Then you should have a blur on top only and sharp on bottom.

Comment: @PeterRader, what you asking for is a very realistic, and while the `blur()` adds some realism to the result, you can't have "gradiently" blurred shadow, becauseAFAIK the blur amount of CSS shadow (both `box-shadow` and `drop-shadow()`)  is distributed evenly around all sides, so you cannot achieve the goal you're after with this markup, you may use SVG or PNG image for the shadow...

Comment: *However*, we can still fake it a little more to get what you need, by using a `span` for example inside the "shadowed" div, and give it only gradient from fully transparent to semi-gradient, with distance shift exact to the plur amount to that on he lower part of the shadow (when it is semi-transparent) it covers the blurred edge of the shadow, and for the upper part it won't cover anything because it is being *gradually* fully transparent. [**check this fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/h6a9vmdy/1/)

Comment: you can even prepend that `span` automatically using javascript, like in [**this demo fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/h6a9vmdy/2/)

Comment: Oh that fiddle looks great!